# Output JSON for WordPress posts

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am using [JSON-API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#5.2.-Developing-JSON-API-controllers) plugin for WordPress and I am creating a custom controller that returns a list of posts from a post type. The output I want is something like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Sample Post Title"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Sample Post Title"
},
....
]
```

here is my custom controller:

```
class JSON_API_Custom_Controller {

 public function get_posts_type() {
    global $json_api;

    $posts_all     = array();

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'shopping', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);

        $posts_all []= array(
         'id' => $post_id,
         'title' => $post_title
        );

      endwhile;
    }

   return $posts_all;

  }

}
```

but the output is :

```
{  
   "status":"ok",
   "0":{  
      "id":1,
      "title":"sample title"
   },
   "1":{  
      "id":2,
      "title":"sample title"
   }
}
```

how can I output the json array of objects like the desired output?

Comment: wow seems like Down Vote guy is here down voting everything without a reason !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose adding `status:ok` to json response is a feature of a plugin.

So, you can modify you function to return an array with one key:

```
// not this 
//return $posts_all;

// but this
return array('posts' => $posts_all);
```

After that, you will still have `status` key in your json response, but also you will have `posts` key, that you can iterate over.

**Update:**
I suppose, the filter `json_api_encode` may help you. You can unset `status` key there:

```
add_filter('json_api_encode', 'remove_status');

function remove_status($response) {
    unset($response['status']);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: the api actually returns the encoded json, I just have to make sure it is in the correct form. Is there anyway I can remove `ok` and `posts` ?

Comment: awesome :) thanks for going through the documentation to find a solution to the problem. Not sure why someone down voted the question and all the answers, but I marked the response as the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Hope the below code will do that for you.

```
 return json_encode($posts_all);
```

To get that "Status" as in example output, you need to add the same in your code.

Comment: the api actually returns the encoded json, there is no need to for this

Comment: Rain, Please go through the code, hope you can understand what I am trying to tell you, 
<?php
    $arr[0]=array('id'=>123,'post_title'=>'test');
    $arr[1]=array('id'=>124,'post_title'=>'test1');

    echo json_encode($arr);

?>